# Тестирование rest java

Tags: java, rest, junit

Хотелось бы узнать,как правильно тестировать rest сервисы.Например,я хочу протестировать post и get методы какого-нибудь сервиса работающего с бд,у него есть post метод для добавления и get для получения объекта.
Я создаю объект -> посылаю post запрос c этим объектом,сервис принимает его -> сохраняет его в бд.И по статусу ответа я принимаю решение правильно ли отработал контроллер или нет.Меня смущает,тот факт,что для тестирования запроса,бд приходится производить реальные операции и манипуляции с объектом.В последствии его(тистируемый объект) нужно будет удалить из бд.Правильный ли это подход для post запроса?Так же с get,чтобы понять правильно-ли он работает,я создаю объект с заранее известными параметрами и поллями->посылаю post->принимаю параметры сравниваю каждое поле,чтобы понять тот ли это объект,и принимаю решение,что все верно.Тут же получается,что при тестировании get метода внутри я должен использовать post.Я слышал,что это не хороший подход.Как мне быть в такой ситуации?Буду рад за любую помощь и ресурсы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно для таких тестов используют чистую базу. Вы генерируете тестовые данные, которые отражают специфику логики сервиса и затем вызываете GET запросы, проверяя все ли поля возвращены корректно.

Для пост-запросов обратный механизм. Возврат сервисом "хорошего" статуса еще не говорит о том, что сама бизнес-логика заранилась корректно. После пост запроса необходимо "залезть" в базу и проверить корректность создания объекта в ней.

После каждого post-теста желательно чистить ту часть схемы базы, которая отвечает за рамещение тестируемых объектов.

**P.S.** - тестирование GET при помощи POST и наоборот также имеет место быть, однако такие тесты встречаются реже, потому как потенциальная ошибка в функционале POST может привести к фолс-позитив/негатив результатам в тестах для GET и наоборот.

Comment: забыл добавить,что после post запроса,в ответ возвращается тот объект который мы отправили,поэтому можно считать,что мы однозначно можем определить корректно ли отработал post метод.у меня больше вопрос в том,что если это какой то удаленный открытый rest api,в котором я не могу проверять бд или создать чистую бд на его основе,то кроме как создать в бд запись и впоследствии ее удаить,никак не обойтись?

Comment: Даже если POST-запрос в ответ возвращает созданный объект - это еще не означает что этот объект создался правильно. Если мы смотрим на сервис как на черный ящик, мы не знаем механизм реализации такого ответа на пост-запрос. Может быть он возвращает входящий объект в ответ еще до того как персистит объект в базу. Очевидно, в Вашем случае остается довольствоваться только косвенными признаками успешности операции.

Comment: не думал с этой точки зрения,видимо,чтобы до конца удостовериться придется выполнить get на всю таблицу

Answer (score 0):

Методика тестирования единая для всех. Извиняюсь пишу как я вижу это своими словами.

1. У Вас есть тестируемый объект. Метод, класс, сервис ....
2. У Вас есть верный результат или же вы знаете верный результат.
3. У Вас есть тестируемая среда. Компьютер, доступ к препаратам, подопытные.
4. Вы тестируете (проводите эксперимент) и проверяете ожидаемое с реальным
   а. Исходное состояние
   б. тест
   с. заключительное состояние
   д. сверка - заключение

применительно к базам данных
если ваш тест предполагает прямая сверка данных с базой данных то это один тест если не предполагает (у вас нет доступа к базе данных) то это другой тест но методика остается.

Comment: понятное дело,что ожидаю я новую запись в бд,но у меня нет доступа к ней,и посмотреть в открытую я не могу,единственный выход,это отрпавить get запрос для получения всех записей с бд,но это уже получается вызов другого теста из теста,что приводит к сильной зависимости друг от друга

Comment: это не вызов другого теста, а вызов другого метода. Это разные вещи, если для успешного завершения теста вам нужно вызвать другой метод то это нормально.

Comment: ну пример,у меня junit вызывает 2 теста на post и get в случайном порядке,если вдруг первым вызывается метод get,а внтри него отправляется post запрос(который еще даже не проверен работает ли он верно),то результат теста может быть ошибочно положительным,разве нет?

Comment: Слушайте, нельзя ходить по земле не опираясь. Так вот вам всё равно нужно от чего-то отходить. тестируете post, значит get считаем верным. Тестируете get значит post  считаем верным